# Como alinhar itens um ao lado do outro?

Tags: html, css

Então,

Eu estou mexendo com bootstrap, html e css.

Preciso alinhar duas colunas e que os itens fiquem alinhados uns aos outros desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu no momento se encontra assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: #383412;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top:15px;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
textarea:focus, input:focus, select:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    outline: 0;
}

..col-sm-6 {
    font-size: 15px;
    ;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Fotos*/

/*Form-w3*/
.w3-input {
    border: none;
}

.container cabec {
    background-color: #39393a;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #cccccc;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.col-sm {
    font-size: 2em;
}

col-sm-ft {
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
}

/*SEARCH*/
.active-purple .fa, .active-purple-2 .fa {
    color: #ce93d8;
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            DADOS DA SS
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            FOTOS
        </div>
        <div class=".col-sm-6">
            <label>NOME:</label><br />
            <input type="text" class="w3-input" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;" /><br />
            <label>E-MAIL:</label>
            <input type="email" class="w3-input" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;" /><br />
            <form class="form-inline active-purple-4">
                <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true">ATIVO:</i><br/>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"><br/><br/>
            </form>

            <label>DATA E HORA DA ABERTURA:</label><br /><br />
            <label>DATA:</label>
            <input type="date" class="w3-input" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;" />
            <label>HORA:</label>
            <input type="time" class="w3-input" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;" /><br />
            <label>ATIVIDADE:</label><br />
            <select>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>#</option>
            </select><br /><br />
            <label>TIPO DE SOLICITAÇÃO DE SERVIÇO:</label><br />
            <select>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>#</option>
             </select><br /><br />
             <label>DESCRIÇÃO DA OS:</label><br />
             <input type="text" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloca o html pois o CSS não é o suficiente para entendermos o que você está fazendo e ajudar-lhe com o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Vc tem certeza que esta usando Bootstrap, qual versão do Bootstrap esta usando? Pois as classes css que vc postou ai são do W3.CSS ... E não do Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa amigo,
Deixa eu entender melhor...
Você que alinhar o Título "DADOS DA SS" com o conjunto de formulários abaixo ? 
Caso sim, Basta você inserir o Título "Dados da SS" em baixo da primeira div da col, ficando assim:

```
<div class=".col-sm-6">
<h1> Dados da SS </h1>
```

e não criando uma col para o título como você fez aqui:

```
 <div class="col-sm">
                    DADOS DA SS
                </div>
```

Para entender melhor o sistema de grid que o bootstrap possuí, sugiro você efetuar a leitura desse [artigo sobre flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background), Depois de ler isso você dificilmente terá problemas para posicionar qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, com as próprias classes do bootstrap você consegue fazer o que deseja.
Tente algo como isso

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Perceba que o posicionamento dos elementos é feito utilizando apenas o grid do bootstrap. Basta você entender o funcionamento do mesmo e aplicar à sua necessidade.

Recomendo dar uma olhada nesses links:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/